# GridView (of ImageViews) : setOnTouchListener and setOnItemClickListener implementation

Tags: android, gridview, ontouchlistener, onitemclicklistener

Currently I have a GridView that holds some ImageViews. The GridView implements setOnItemClickListener. When the onItemClick occurs, the user gets a dialog and on back pressed or on dismiss, he returns to the current GridView.
Till now everything works fine.

I would like to know if there is a way to change the selected imageView (with another image, or even just the alpha).

I have tried inside the setOnItemClickListener to change the image, but when I try to change it back to it's normal image after the dialog.dismiss() call, a white screen pops up for some milliseconds. Although, the image is set correctly, I would like to avoid this white image.

I have tried to implement the GridView.setOnTouchListener, but I would get only a white screen (for some milliseconds) and no other operation would be executed (no pop up dialog).

I even tried to implement OnTouchListener inside the ViewHolder class and although it seemed to work with some problems (changing the alpha on ACTION_DOWN was permanent, so I had to reselect the same item to change the alpha back to normal), the setOnItemClickListener wouldn't work at all.

Can someone help me with this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for anyone having the same problem, I used TransitionDrawable. Inside my imageAdapter, I loaded the transition xml files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/soft"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/soft_pressed"/>

</transition>
```

and on gridview.setOnItemClickListener, I used this sample of code:

```
ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
final ImageView imageview = holder.image;
((TransitionDrawable)imageview.getDrawable()).startTransition(2000);
```

And to execute the next command (some delay is needed):

```
 final Handler handler = new Handler();
 handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    YourMethod(...);
    //reverse the transition
((TransitionDrawable)imageview.getDrawable()).reverseTransition(2000);
    }
  }, 2000);
```